# Echo all results from sql join when using group by

Tags: php, sql, group-by, while-loop, left-join

I have the following query which I run via PHP:

```
select 
    {$tableProducts}.*,
    {$tableImages}.*
from {$tableProducts}
left join {$tableImages}
    on {$tableImages}.product_id = {$tableProducts}.product_id
group by {$tableProducts}.product_id;
```

Each product (from product table) can have several images (in images table). I loop through the results with a simple while statement:

```
while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    echo $row->product_name; // Product table
    echo $row->image_src; // Image table
}
```

**Problem:** Only the first image of each product is printed, but I want to display all of them. All images are printed if I remove the "order by" part, but then the product_name is printed once for each image (so if one product has three images, the product_name would be printed three times as well).

How do I best solve this?

Comment: You wrote `order by` instead of `group by` in your example query.

Comment: please run the query once on phpmyadmin or query console(you use) to see the result what actually getting from Query ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how `GROUP BY` works.

If you want to get all images for all products, you can solve that (at least) 3 ways:

**1**: Do not use `GROUP BY`, handle it in the loop, like:

```
$last_product = null;
while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
    if ($last_product !== $row->product_id) {
        // new product starts here
        $last_product = $row->product_id;
        echo $row->product_name; // Product table
    }
    echo $row->image_src; // Image table
}
```

**2**: Use `GROUP BY` & query all images with different statements within the loop.

```
$products = <query products>;

while($row = $products->fetch_object()) {
    echo $row->product_name; // Product table

    $images = <query images for product in $row>;
    while($row = $images->fetch_object()) {
        echo $row->image_src; // Image table
    }
}
```

**3**: Use aggregate string functions to get all images for a product. This is only works in special cases, f.ex. here, as URL cannot consist new lines, for example.

In `MySQL`:

```
select 
    {$tableProducts}.*,
    group_concat({$tableImages}.image_src SEPARATOR '\n') as image_srcs
from {$tableProducts}
left join {$tableImages}
    on {$tableImages}.product_id = {$tableProducts}.product_id
group by {$tableProducts}.product_id;
```

In `PostgreSQL`:

```
select 
    {$tableProducts}.*,
    string_agg({$tableImages}.image_src, '\n') as image_srcs
from {$tableProducts}
left join {$tableImages}
    on {$tableImages}.product_id = {$tableProducts}.product_id
group by {$tableProducts}.product_id;
```

In the loop:

```
while($row = $products->fetch_object()) {
    echo $row->product_name; // Product table
    foreach (explode("\n", $row->image_srcs) as $image_src) {
        echo $image_src; // Image table
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer @pozs! I'm not a big fan of method 2 since I don't think it's good for performance to run a new query for each image. I tested method 3 and it works great, but I might change to method 1 - haven't decided yet :)

Comment: One follow up question if I use method 3: What if I also have image_alt in the images table? Should I do multiple explodes and if so; how?

Comment: As I wrote URLs are special. `alt` can contain any characters, so we can't choose a separator for them (as if one `alt` contains the separator, that `alt` would be splitted up, and you will get more `alt`s than urls).